# JavaScript game functions not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I posted yesterday and I basically just restarted it in order to lose the margin:auto and made some of my images display:inline in lists to be more organized with positioning and everything, and to get rid of any error with my CSS. It must be a problem with my JavaScript- none of my functions are working, and I cannot find the mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Here](http://udel.edu/~muldoon/finalproject/index.html) is what the game looks like so far and [here](http://udel.edu/~muldoon/finalproject/index.css) is my CSS just in case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Santa Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script>
        var topsanta = 335;
        var leftsanta = 800;
        var topkid = new Array ();
        topkid[0] = 520;
        topkid[1] = 520;
        topkid[2] = 520;
        topkid[3] = 520;
        topkid[4] = 520;
        var leftkid = new Array ();
        leftkid[0] = 565;
        leftkid[1] = 415;
        leftkid[2] = 265;
        leftkid[3] = 115;
        leftkid[4] = -35;
        var kidid = new Array ();
        kidid[0] = "kid5";
        kidid[1] = "kid4";
        kidid[2] = "kid3";
        kidid[3] = "kid2";
        kidid[4] = "kid1";
        var kiddirect = new Array ();
        kiddirect[0] = -10;
        kiddirect[1] = -10;
        kiddirect[2] = -10;
        kiddirect[3] = -10;
        kiddirect[4] = -10;
        var kidmax = new Array ();
        kidmax[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
        kidmax[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
        kidmax[2] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
        kidmax[3] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
        kidmax[4] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
        var topstorm = new Array ();
        topstorm[0] = 75;
        topstorm[1] = 75;
        topstorm[2] = 75;
        topstorm[3] = 75;
        var leftstorm = new Array ();
        leftstorm[0] = 550;
        leftstorm[1] = 400;
        leftstorm[2] = 250;
        leftstorm[3] = 100;
        var stormid = new Array ();
        stormid[0] = "storm4";
        stormid[1] = "storm3";
        stormid[2] = "storm2";
        stormid[3] = "storm1";
        var stormdirect = new Array ();
        stormdirect[0] = 10;
        stormdirect[1] = 10;
        stormdirect[2] = 10;
        stormdirect[3] = 10;
        var stormmax = new Array ();
        stormmax[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
        stormmax[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
        stormmax[2] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
        stormmax[3] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
        var score = 0;
        function movesanta(direct)
        {
            if(direct.keyCode == 37)
            {
                document.getElementById("santa").style.position="absolute";
                leftsanta = leftsanta - 10;
                document.getElementById("santa").style.left=leftsanta+"px";
            }
            else if(direct.keyCode == 39)
            {
                document.getElementById("santa").style.position="absolute";
                leftsanta = leftsanta + 10;
                document.getElementById("santa").style.left=leftsanta+"px";
            }
            else if(direct.keyCode == 38)
            {
                document.getElementById("santa").style.position="absolute";
                topsanta = topsanta - 10;
                document.getElementById("santa").style.top=topsanta+"px";
            }
            else if(direct.keyCode == 40)
            {
                document.getElementById("santa").style.position="absolute";
                topsanta = topsanta + 10;
                document.getElementById("santa").style.top=topsanta+"px";
            }
            else if (leftsanta < 3)
            {
                score = score + 10;
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Santa score = "+score;
            }
            else if (score >= 100)
            {
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="You win!!!";
            }
        }
        function start()
        {
            movekid(0);
            movekid(1);
            movekid(2);
            movekid(3);
            movekid(4);
            movestorm(0);
            movestorm(1);
            movestorm(2);
            movestorm(3);
        }
        function starteasier()
        {
            movekideasier(0);
            movekideasier(1);
            movekideasier(2);
            movekideasier(3);
            movekideasier(4);
            movestormeasier(0);
            movestormeasier(1);
            movestormeasier(2);
            movestormeasier(3);
        }
        function movekid(x)
        {
            topkid[x] = topkid[x] + kiddirect[x];
            document.getElementById(kidid[x]).style.top=topkid[x]+"px";
            if (topkid[x] < kidmax[x])
            {
                kiddirect[x] = kiddirect[x] * -1;
            }
            else if (topkid[x] > 520)
            {
                kiddirect[x] = kiddirect[x] * -1;
                kidmax[x] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
            }
            else if (( leftsanta > leftkid[x] - 20) && (leftsanta < leftkid[x] + 20))
            {
                score = score - 10;
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Santa score = "+score;
            }
            else if (( topsanta > topkid[x] - 20) && (topsanta < topkid[x] + 20))
            {
                score = score - 10;
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Santa score = "+score;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){movekid(x)},100);
        }
        function movekideasier(x)
        {
            topkid[x] = topkid[x] + kiddirect[x];
            document.getElementById(kidid[x]).style.top=topkid[x]+"px";
            if (topkid[x] < kidmax[x]);
            {
                kiddirect[x] = kiddirect[x] * -1;
            }
            if (topkid[x] > 520)
            {
                kiddirect[x] = kiddirect[x] * -1;
                kidmax[x] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
            }
            else if (( leftsanta > leftkid[x] - 20) && (leftsanta < leftkid[x] + 20))
            {
                score = score - 10;
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Santa score = "+score;
            }
            else if (( topsanta > topkid[x] - 20) && (topsanta < topkid[x] + 20))
            {
                score = score - 10;
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Santa score = "+score;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){movekid(x)},500);
        }
        function movestorm(x)
        {
            topstorm[x] = topstorm[x] + stormdirect[x];
            document.getElementById(stormid[x]).style.top=topstorm[x]+"px";
            if (topstorm[x] < stormmax[x])
            {
                stormdirect[x] = stormdirect[x] * -1;
            }
            else if (topstorm[x] > 520)
            {
                stormdirect[x] = stormdirect[x] * -1;
                stormmax[x] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
            }
            else if (( leftsanta > leftstorm[x] - 20) && (leftsanta < leftstorm[x] + 20))
            {
                score = score - 10;
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Santa score = "+score;
            }
            else if (( topsanta > topstorm[x] - 20) && (topsanta < topstorm[x] + 20))
            {
                score = score - 10;
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Santa score = "+score;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){movestorm(x)},100);
        }
        function movestormeasier(x)
        {
            topstorm[x] = topstorm[x] + stormdirect[x];
            document.getElementById(stormid[x]).style.top=topstorm[x]+"px";
            if (topstorm[x] < stormmax[x])
            {
                stormdirect[x] = stormdirect[x] * -1;
            }
            else if (topstorm[x] > 520)
            {
                stormdirect[x] = stormdirect[x] * -1;
                stormmax[x] = Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+150;
            }
            else if (( leftsanta > leftstorm[x] - 20) && (leftsanta < leftstorm[x] + 20))
            {
                score = score - 10;
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Santa score = "+score;
            }
            else if (( topsanta > topstorm[x] - 20) && (topsanta < topstorm[x] + 20))
            {
                score = score - 10;
                document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Santa score = "+score;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){movestorm(x)},500);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onKeyPress="movesanta(event)">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="top">
                <p id="p1">Help Santa avoid storms and the eyes of curious children to deliver all the presents on time!</h1>
                <p id="p2">Santa score: 0</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="middle">
                <ul id="clouds1div">
                    <li><img class="clouds1class" id="cloud1" src="cloud.png" width="200px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds1class" id="cloud2" src="cloud.png" width="200px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds1class" id="cloud3" src="cloud.png" width="200px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds1class" id="cloud4" src="cloud.png" width="200px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds1class" id="cloud5" src="cloud.png" width="200px"></li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="stormsdiv">
                    <li><img class="stormsclass" id="storm1" src="storm.png" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="stormsclass" id="storm2" src="storm.png" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="stormsclass" id="storm3" src="storm.png" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="stormsclass" id="storm4" src="storm.png" width="150px"></li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="clouds2div">
                    <li><img class="clouds2class" id="cloud6" src="cloud.png" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds2class" id="cloud7" src="cloud.png" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds2class" id="cloud8" src="cloud.png" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds2class" id="cloud9" src="cloud.png" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds2class" id="cloud10" src="cloud.png" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds2class" id="cloud11" src="cloud.png" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="clouds2class" id="cloud12" src="cloud.png" width="150px"></li>
                </ul>
                <img id="hill" src="hill.png" width="785px" height="100px">
                <ul id="kidsdiv">
                    <li><img class="kidsclass" id="kid1" src="kid1.png" width="100px"></li>
                    <li><img class="kidsclass" id="kid2" src="kid2.png" width="100px"></li>
                    <li><img class="kidsclass" id="kid3" src="kid3.png" width="100px"></li>
                    <li><img class="kidsclass" id="kid4" src="kid4.png" width="100px"></li>
                    <li><img class="kidsclass" id="kid5" src="kid5.png" width="100px"></li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="housesdiv">
                    <li><img class="housesclass" id="house1" src="house.gif" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="housesclass" id="house2" src="house.gif" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="housesclass" id="house3" src="house.gif" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="housesclass" id="house4" src="house.gif" width="150px"></li>
                    <li><img class="housesclass" id="house5" src="house.gif" width="150px"></li>
                </ul>
                <img id="santa" src="santa.gif" width="250px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="bottom">
                <div id="arrowsdiv">
                    <span class="arrowsclass" id="up" ><!--onClick="movesanta('up')">-->&#8593;</span>
                    <span class="arrowsclass" id="left" ><!--onClick="movesanta('left')">-->&#8592;</span>
                    <span class="arrowsclass" id="right" ><!--onClick="movesanta('right')">-->&#8594;</span>
                    <span class="arrowsclass" id="down" ><!--onClick="movesanta('down')">-->&#8595;</span>
                </div>
                <div id="buttonsdiv">
                    <button type="button" onClick="starteasier()">Start (Easy)</button>
                    <button type="button" onClick="start()">Start (Hard)</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>           
</body>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Why are you assigning individual array elements?! A good 50% of the code is just duplicated!

Comment: @AndrewLi I have multiple images that all need to move up and down at differently- if you look at the link at what the game looks like without anything moving, you'll notice they are hidden between the two sets of clouds and then some between the houses and snow hill at the bottom. Also I have two versions of the game, one easier, and one harder.

Comment: Then why not initialize the array with those values? Put common code *outside* your if statements, and maybe loops will help you out...

Answer (score 0):

Your minus signs are the wrong unicode character, replace the minus sign in all such if conditions

current code

```
if (( leftsanta > leftkid[x] – 20) && (leftsanta < leftkid[x] + 20))
```

after correction

```
if (( leftsanta > leftkid[x] - 20) && (leftsanta < leftkid[x] + 20))
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that but none of my keys or buttons are still working

Comment: onClick="movesanta('right')" is incorrect movesanta method expects an argument of type KeyboardEvent. You are checking for keyCode property yet you are passing a string to it, "up", "right" etc. There are a number of ways you can fix this. Try using a new method  for handling mouse click events

Comment: start and starteasier methods are in fact 'working' but there are logical errors in them. Please try debugging the code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript

Comment: I just now used the debugger/error console on Safari, Firefox, and Chrome and none of them show any errors